# Alterar cor do ícone de uma Tab selecionada

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo abas no Android Studio com **com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout** e gostaria de alterar a cor do ícone, **somente** da aba selecionada.

Os ícones estão em SVG. E as cores do texto e dos ícones são diferentes, então não posso usar o style padrão.

Versão da API: 30

Versão do Android Studio: 4.1.1

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabInlineLabel="true">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ir agora"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_imediatas"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ir outro dia"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_programadas"
        />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Na Activity, fiz a seguinte tentativa:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setTint(R.color.icon_tab_selected);
        //tabLayout.setTabIconTintResource(R.color.icon_tab_selected);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tabLayout.setTabIconTintResource(R.color.icon_tab_unselected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Porém acaba alterando as cores de todas as abas, e a cor fica incorreta, parece que muda somente o contraste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, parte da sua pergunta já tem a resposta. Sim você precisará criar uma customização com dois `<selector>`

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg_color_selector"
    app:tabIconTint="@color/tab_content_color_selector"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/red"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/secondaryColor">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pedidos"
        android:text="Pedidos" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_suporte"
        android:text="Suporte" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

drawable/tab_bg_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/secondaryColor" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

color/tab_content_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/secondaryColor" />
</selector>
```

**EDIT:**
Importante: os ícones você altera para os seus. Este é um exemplo aqui em uso em um app e os ícones são também em SVG. Modifique para que atenda as suas necessidades.

Comment: Perfeito, só complementando sobre as cores diferentes, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema. Seguindo o exemplo da resposta, no _color/tab_content_color_selector.xml_ eu tinha colocado `android:drawable`, por isso fica a cor errada.

Comment: @DennerLuan pois é... Color não é Drawable. É um resource diferente.